# How to make search input case insensitive for txt file

Tags: python

Right now the code is working but if I don't capitalize the first letter of both first and last name the code will return "error: person not found."

How can I set it up so that no matter how the user inputs the search it will return the requested data?

```
#Iterate through the lines and save them in a dictionary, with the
#full name as the key
for line in file:
    stripped = line.strip()
    name = stripped[:stripped.index(',')]
    d[name] = stripped[stripped.index(',')+1:].strip()
```

def main():

```
#call the input function to read the file
addresses = input_address()

#Get the user option
option = int(input("Lookup (1) phone numbers or (2) addresses: "))

if option == 1:
    phone = True
else:
    phone = False

#Ask for names and print their information in case they exist, end on blank entry
while True:
    name = input("Enter space-separated first and last name: ")

    if name == "":
        return main()
    if name not in addresses:
        print("Error: person not found")
    else:
        display(addresses[name], phone)
```

main()

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
.capitalize()
```

For example:

```
'hello world'.capitalize()
```

yields,

```
'Hello World'
```

So in your case, you would do:

```
name.capitalize()
```

then look for it inside addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lower()`, `upper()`, or `capitalize()`, as long as you attach the chosen method to end of both variables.

Using `lower()`:

```
for i in range(len(addresses)):
   addresses[i] = addresses[i].lower()   # Converting array values to lowercase

if name.lower() not in addresses:    # Seeing if lowercase variable is in lowercase array
   print("Error: person not found")
else:
   print("Person found")
```